# Magento Catalog Model Product Image

Tags: php, image, magento, product

I have a Magento site where I make use of an extension which, among other things, creates new product images with a better compression and stores them under a dedicated path.
I also have a routine that builds an xml sitemap, including images.
My problem is that while the new images are loaded in product pages, I still get the old urls like /media/catalog/product/cache/ from my routine.

The code executed is like this:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('xsitemap/catalog_product_xml')
            ->getCollection($this->_storeId, false, $limit, $this->_counter);

$this->_counter += $limit;
foreach ($collection as $item) {
    if ($isProductImages) {
        $imageUrl = array();
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
        $product->setStore($this->_storeId);
        $product->load($item->getId());
        if(is_object($product)) {
            $imageObj = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'image');
            $urlIm = $imageObj->__toString();
            $imageUrl[] = $urlIm;
        }
    }
}
```

The strage thing is that if I run this code from outside the extension, using a temporary class under Magento root, I get a different url for the same product, precisely the new image url.
I don't get why I should get different results, if the instructions are the same.
My temp class is written like this, by the way:

```
<?php
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::app();

class Pippo {

    public $_helper;
    public $_storeId;
    public $_storeBaseUrl;

    public function __construct() {

    }

    public function __init() {
        $this->_storeId = 1;
        $this->_helper = Mage::helper('xsitemap');
        $this->_helper->init($this->_storeId);
        $this->_storeBaseUrl        = "http://www.example.com";

        $isProductImages     = $this->_helper->isProductImages();

        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('xsitemap/catalog_product_xml')
                    ->getCollection(1, false);

        foreach ($collection as $item) {
            $url     = $this->_storeBaseUrl . $item->getUrl();
            //$lastmod = $this->_getItemChangeDate($item);
            if ($isProductImages) {
                $imageUrl = array();
                $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
                $product->setStore($this->_storeId);
                $product->load($item->getId());
                if(is_object($product)) {
                    $imageObj = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'image');
                    $urlIm = $imageObj->__toString();
                    $imageUrl[] = $urlIm;
                    var_dump($imageUrl); exit;
                }   
            }
        }
    }   
}
$pippo = new Pippo();
$pippo->__init(); 
?>
```

Comment: Can you post your full code showing how you have overridden the default product image helper method. i.e. Mage::helper('catalog/image'). Might be easier to replicate the default helper into your own module and adjust accordingly and keep the default as default. You can of course change templates  to make use of your own helper instead of magentos inbuilt one.

Comment: Ok, I found that Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Image is overridden by another extension. The problem is that when I retrieve products from my sitemap extension, the default class is used, instead of the override one. Why do I get this behaviour?

Comment: Have you got a rewrite rule defined in your config.xml file? If there is another module rewriting the default module, you should setup a rewrite rule in your module for the third party instead of the default module. You could be experiencing module conflict. See http://www.aschroder.com/2013/04/understanding-and-detecting-magento-extension-clashes-or-conflicts/